# Función para eliminar ítem en listview con Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sqlite

Me falta implementar la función de borrado para mi listview, cuyo registro también se borre en la base de datos. La idea es mantener presionado uno de los ítems del listview y que arroje el mensaje si realmente quiere eliminar el objeto seleccionado, al dar que sí este debería borrarse de la base de datos y del listview. El listview muestra normalmente los datos de la base de datos, solo me falta el borrado.

```kotlin
class ListView : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        lateinit var  helperDB : SQLite
        private lateinit var binding: ActivityListViewBinding
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view)
    
            binding = ActivityListViewBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)
    
            helperDB = SQLite(this,"MiLista",null,1)
    
            val db : SQLiteDatabase = helperDB.readableDatabase
            var movileArray = arrayOf(db)
            val cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT rowid _id,* FROM productosSQL",null)
            val adaptador = CursorAdapterListView(this, cursor)
            binding.lvDatos.adapter = adaptador
            db.close()
            fun Eliminar(){
    
                var listview: ListView = binding.lvDatos
    
                val adapter : ArrayAdapter<*> = ArrayAdapter<Any?>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, movileArray)
                listview.adapter = adapter
                
    
            }
            fun getAllNames():ArrayList<String>?{
    
    
                try {
                    val listadoProduc = ArrayList<String>()
                    db
                    var con = SQLite(this,"MiLista",null,1)
    
    
                    //vemos si hay datos guardados
                    val numdatos = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "productosSQL").toInt()
                    if (numdatos>0){
                        val consulta = "SELECT tipo FROM productosSQL "
                        val p = db.rawQuery(consulta,null)
    
                        //nos posicionamos en el primer elemento
    
                        p.moveToFirst()
    
                        do {
                            //llenamos arreglo de respuesta
                            listadoProduc.add(p.getString(0))
                        }while (p.moveToNext())
    
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this, "NO hay productos guardados", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                    db.close()
                    return listadoProduc
                    }catch (ex:Exception){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "NO se contaron datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    return null
                }
            }
    
    
    
        }



    inner class CursorAdapterListView(context: Context, cursor : Cursor) : CursorAdapter(context,cursor,
        FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER
    ){
        override fun newView(context : Context?, cursor: Cursor?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
        }

        override fun bindView(view: View?, context: Context?, cursor: Cursor?) {
            val bindingItems = ItemBinding.bind(view!!)
            bindingItems.tvListaTipo.text = cursor!!.getString(2)
            bindingItems.tvListaMarca.text = cursor!!.getString(3)
            bindingItems.tvListadescripcion.text = cursor!!.getString(4)
            bindingItems.tvListaCantidad.text = cursor!!.getString(5)

        }

    }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo implementar una función que me ayude con esto?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento para implementar la función de borrado? Lee [ask].

Comment: Intente por medio de tutoriales de youtube, los cuales hacen un método con la consulta sql respectiva, mi problema esta en que no se como asociar el listview y el metodo de eliminacion. La idea es mantener presionado el item del listview que se desea borrar, esto por medio de setOnLongClickListener, el cual pregunta si realmente se desea eliminar el elemento. al dar que si, deberia borrarse el elemento tanto del listview como de la base de datos, pero lo que intente me resulto inutil.